# Serializable object to Arraylist of Hashmap

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am developing an android application, where I display all the names of the contact in a Listview.

Onclick of the contact Listview,I need to display the respective numbers of that Contact in another Listview.

The problem here is, I bundled all the numbers and sent it another activity and also received the bundle, but the received bundle is Serializable object.

So, to dispaly in the Listview I need to convert it to the Arraylist of Hashmap.
How can I do this?

Here is the code:

Sending Activity:

```
HashMap<String, String> Numbermap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Numbermap.put("numb",number);
Numbermap.put("type",type);

NumberList.add(Numbermap);

Intent intent = new Intent (ContactNames.this,ContactsPhoneNumbers.class);

intent.putExtra("map", NumberList);


startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving Activity:

```
    Serializable Numbermap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //  contNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ContactNumber);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        Numbermap = bundle.getSerializable("map");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put into the intent with the key "map", the object `NumberList` which is an instance of `ArrayList` I think. But in your activity `ContactsPhoneNumbers`, you try to get with the key "map" an instance of HashMap, which is not correct.

Here is what you just should do:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> numberList = null;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(bundle!=null)
{
    numberList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.getSerializable("map");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code in following way.

Sending Activity:

```
    HashMap<String, String> Numbermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> NumberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Numbermap.put("numb", "1");
    Numbermap.put("type", "type");
    NumberList.add(Numbermap);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("map", NumberList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Reciving activity:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> NumberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        NumberList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) extras.get("map");
        System.out.println(NumberList.get(0));
```

My logcat output is:

```
06-21 17:14:59.729: I/System.out(1609): {numb=1, type=type}
```

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Serializable` object is de-serialized into the same object type when received by the other `Activity`. Just cast it to `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> numberList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.getSerializable("map");
```

**Note:** This will give you a compiler warning, because you cast a generic type. It can be ignored or suppressed, as long as you make sure the types match on both sides.
Generally, it is error-prone to cast generic types. A better solution would be to use a serializable class containing the data, which is more type-safe:

```
public class MyNumbersClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Map<String,String>> data;

    public MyNumbersClass(List<Map<String,String>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyNumbersClass() {
    }

    public List<Map<String,String>>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then just create an instance of this class, passing your `ArrayList` to the constructor. On the other side, cast the `Serializable` to `MyNumbersClass` and use `getData()` to retrieve the list.