# How to put List<HashMap> into Bundle?

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

In my Fragment, there is a

`List<HashMap> movieList`

How could I store movieList into Bundle in

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializable object to Arraylist of Hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233566/serializable-object-to-arraylist-of-hashmap)

Comment: You are welcome to try to make the whole structure `Serializable`. That being said, I am skeptical that this is the sort of thing that should go into the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: @BertrandMartel Thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way...

```
HashMap<String, String> contactsMap = new HashMap<>();
contactsMap.put("key1" , "value1");
contactsMap.put("key2" , "value2");

ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(contactsMap);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("HASHMAP", list);

ArrayList<HashMap> hashmapList = (ArrayList<HashMap>)            b.getSerializable("HASHMAP");
HashMap<String, String> map = hashmapList.get(0);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
}
```

You will get the same data. Make sure your movie model class is serializable.

Comment: Thank you Prashant. I just found ArrayList is Serializable.